# Post notification using NSDistributionCenter in sandboxed apps

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsnotifications

I am looking at ways on sending message from my main app to helper app. Its just a one way communication. I came accross XPC, unix sockets and NSDistributioncenter and found that posting notifications was the simplest one.

I am using `postNotificationName:object:` to send notifications.

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"aNote" 
                                                               object:@"Hello"];
```

In helper app I have added observers in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` to receive notifications.

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                    selector:@selector(hello:)
                                                        name:@"aNote"
                                                      object:nil];
```

But it can only get notified if sandboxing is turned off. In the Apple docs it does say that `userInfo` must be nil if app is sandboxed but I am not using userInfo. I also tried with `postNotificationName:object:userInfo:` with userInfo `nil` but still it didnt work.

How can I get this to work in Sandboxed apps ?

Comment: please show the receiver ...

Comment: @Daij-Djan I have edited my question. Please let me know if I did something wrong here.